# How to removed NaN values from a list build with row values in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Huy Guys,

I have a column in pandas that is a list with all values from row.
As a sample below.

```
print(df4['List']) 

0 [8,9,10,25,14,25,14,17,19,30]
1 [nan,85,48,75,nan,96,32,14,15,21,28,17,nan]
2 [nan,85,48,75,nan,]
3 [1,nan]
4 [85,75,41,nan]
5 [nan,65,34]
```

How can i do to remove these 'nan' values from my lists?

I tryed some conventional methods of list in python however i don't get
make it have the same result in pandas DataFrame.

As this one:

```
while True:
    try:
        df4['PNs NaNs Removed'] = df4['List'].delete([nan])
    except ValueError:
        break
```

Comment: Why are you storing a list in a pandas DataFrame? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I created a column that contains 1 list with values from line. So i want to remove these 'nan' values from this column and keep valid values.

Comment: I understand your problem, I was curious as to why you were storing lists inside a DataFrame in the first place. The values in your list are actual NaN values, right, not strings like "nan"?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to avoid iterations by using the Series.dropna function:

```
def no_nan(listy):
    return list(pd.Series(listy).dropna())

df4['List'] = df4['List'].apply(no_nan)
```

Comment: Code run without errors, however ```nan``` values remais in list.

Comment: That's odd, it worked for me.  What happens if you create a new column, i.e. df4['List2'] = df4['List'].apply(no_nan)  ?

Comment: ```KeyError: 'List2'```

Comment: Hmm.  I still don't see what we're doing differently.  One more try.  What do you get from x = df4['List'].apply(no_nan)?  That is what is the value of x after?

Comment: I tested this and I can confirm that it works. Any idea what the differences between this and the list comprehension method are?

Comment: I actually just found one myself: The conversion to a Series can mess with the types. The example I tested was a list of integers and `Nan`s, and it cast the integers to floats. So that’s something be aware/careful of.

Comment: The list comprehension method is an iteration at the python level, whereas the Series.dropna() doesn't require python to iterate. So it should be faster for large datasets.

Comment: @mermaldad I don’t know why I didn’t just run some benchmarks when I made that comment lol. I also share your intuition that it should be faster, I will benchmark it tomorrow and report back!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there are many different ways to indicate and handle `NaN` values, and it can get quite messy. This solution tests values using `pandas.isna()` which should work for a wider variety of values than `numpy.isnan()`.

```py
import pandas as pd


df4['List'] = df4['List'].apply(lambda col_val: [item for item in col_val if not pd.isna(item)])
```